# Facing problems in handling HTTPS communication through a python based proxy server

Tags: python, networking, proxy, network-programming

Here's the code I have for the python based proxy server (which is pretty much taken from here: http://voorloopnul.com/blog/a-python-proxy-in-less-than-100-lines-of-code/). The remote server is hard coded here. If I run this proxy and then try to browse for www.google.com through my web browser, I get an empty response.

But when I try to look up for a website which handles data in plain HTTP format, it seems to work fine.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

```
import socket
import select
import time
import sys
import ssl


buffer_size = 4096
delay = 0.0001
forward_to = ('www.google.com', 443)

class Forward:
    def __init__(self):
        self.forward = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start(self, host, port):
        try:
            remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
            self.forward.connect((remote_ip, port))
            return self.forward
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return False

class TheServer:
    input_list = []
    channel = {}
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((host, port))
        self.server.listen(200)
    def main_loop(self):
        self.input_list.append(self.server)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(delay)
            ss = select.select
            inputready, outputready, exceptready = ss(self.input_list, [], [])
            for self.s in inputready:
                if self.s == self.server:
                    self.on_accept()
                    break
                self.data = self.s.recv(buffer_size)
                if len(self.data) == 0:
                    self.on_close()
                    break
                else:
                    self.on_recv()
    def on_accept(self):
        forward = Forward().start(forward_to[0], forward_to[1])
        clientsock, clientaddr = self.server.accept()
        if forward:
            print clientaddr, "has connected"
            self.input_list.append(clientsock)
            self.input_list.append(forward)
            self.channel[clientsock] = forward
            self.channel[forward] = clientsock
        else:
            print "Can't establish connection with remote server.",
            print "Closing connection with client side", clientaddr
            clientsock.close()
    def on_close(self):
        print self.s.getpeername(), "has disconnected"
        #remove objects from input_list
        self.input_list.remove(self.s)
        self.input_list.remove(self.channel[self.s])
        out = self.channel[self.s]
        # close the connection with client
        self.channel[out].close() # equivalent to do self.s.close()
        # close the connection with remote server
        self.channel[self.s].close()
        # delete both objects from channel dict
        del self.channel[out]
        del self.channel[self.s]
    def on_recv(self):
        data = self.data
        # here we can parse and/or modify the data before send forward
        self.channel[self.s].send(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = TheServer('', 8899)
    try:
        server.main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl C - Stopping server"
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Server not accepted proxy query !

Comment: And how do I solve that?